# How to resolve React Redux payload not being passed to state object

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Hey so I am working on an online store,I am using MERN stack. So in this store I have 3 clothing categories:

1. Male Clothes
2. Female Clothes
3. Kids Clothes

So now I would love to handle the users cart, so when the user clicks on the **Add TO Cart** button I send over 3 joint axios get request using the **axios.all** so that I can get the correct item data based on the product ID.

So I do successfully get back the correct product from the server and when I console log out the response I get what I want

Now the problem is the data is not being passed over to the Cart, I even tried to remove the adding logic where now I was adding even if they were duplicates because I thought maybe the logic in the reducer is causing the error so I change it to be just adding anything that comes in so I can narrow down if it was my logic that was breaking but still data in not being passed to the cart can I please get some help here I am really stuck

**Code below is my cartActions.js**

```
const addToCart = (productId, qty) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const femaleProduct_url = `http://127.0.0.1:5000/single-womens-clothes/${productId}`;
    const maleProduct_url = `http://127.0.0.1:5000/single-mens-clothes/${productId}`;
    const kidsProduct_url = `http://127.0.0.1:5000/single-kids-clothes/${productId}`;

    const femaleProduct_request = await axios.get(femaleProduct_url);
    const maleProudct_request = await axios.get(maleProduct_url);
    const kidsProduct_request = await axios.get(kidsProduct_url);
    let data = [];

    axios
      .all([femaleProduct_request, maleProudct_request, kidsProduct_request])
      .then(
        axios.spread((...responses) => {
          const f_product = responses[0];
          const m_product = responses[1];
          const k_product = responses[2];

          if (f_product.data.length > 0) {
            data = f_product.data;
          } else if (m_product.data.length > 0) {
            data = m_product.data;
          } else {
            data = k_product.data;
          }
        })
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("DATA: ", data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

    dispatch({
      type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {}
};

export default addToCart;
```

**Code below is the cartReducer.js**

```
const cartReducer = (state = { cartItems: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CART_ADD_ITEM:
      const item = action.payload;

      return { cartItems: [...state.cartItems, item] };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default cartReducer;
```

Comment: Please share result of console.log(data)

Comment: There's no mapStateToProps function in your component, neither connect. Read the docs: https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/basic-tutorial

Comment: @DavidThery Is the mapStateToProps necessary? I am asking because I have used Redux in the project to manage the fetching of fetching products when one clicks to Male section etc so to render the loading page while data is being fetch and I never used the **mapToStateProps** and it's working just breaking here when I want to handle the cart

Comment: @sgrmhdk I get an empty array when I check from the redux dev tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dispatch `CART_ADD_ITEM` after `axios` end all requests:

```
.then((response) => {
  dispatch({
    type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
    payload: data,
  });
})
```

Also, note that `axios.all` and `axios.spread` [are deprecated](https://github.com/axios/axios#concurrency-deprecated) in favor of `Promise.all`:

```
const femaleProduct_request = axios.get(femaleProduct_url);
const maleProudct_request = axios.get(maleProduct_url);
const kidsProduct_request = axios.get(kidsProduct_url);

Promise.all([femaleProduct_request, maleProudct_request, kidsProduct_request])
  .then((responses) => {
      const f_product = responses[0];
      const m_product = responses[1];
      const k_product = responses[2];

      // [...]

      return data
    })
  .then((data) => {
    dispatch({
      type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
      payload: data,
    });
  })
```